# combining custom error placement with success is not working jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I tried and want to bring the success message as in this demo (iam using bootstrap2)

http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html

However, since iam using errorPlacement function for placing my error messages like this in

```
               errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html(error.text());
    },
```

and Html like this,

```
        <div class="controls">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="input" name="user_login" placeholder="User Name"/>
        <span class="fillimg"> </span>

    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span> 

    </div>
```

and my success goes like this,

```
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html(error.text());
},

            highlight: function(element) {
     $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
success: function(element) {

    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.fillimg').addClass('valid');        
   $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
}
```

and CSS

```
           label.valid {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background: url('/assets/img/admin/valid.png') center center no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            text-indent: -9999px;
           }
           label.error {
           font-weight: bold;
           color: red;
           padding: 2px 8px;
           margin-top: 2px;
          }
```

when i am removing errorPlacement functionality the functionality inside success is working .However, using errorPlacement prevents the success function from adding success class to the .control-group. Please suggest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're mixing up the callback functions.  **I *suggest* that you [read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) for each callback function.**

---

**`errorPlacement`** is used for layout.  When an element is invalid, this callback function tells *where* to place the element on the form.  The default is *after* the element being validated.

---

**`success`** is used to control the `label` when the element is valid.  In other words, by default, there is no `label` when the element is valid, so by using this callback, you can generate one.  Typically, people will use this for placing a icon next to valid elements, like a check-mark.

---

**`highlight`** is triggered whenever there is a validation error and it's used for toggling the default error and valid classes on the element being tested.

---

**`unhighlight`** is triggered whenever the validation error is corrected and it's used for toggling the default error and valid classes on the element being tested.  **It's the exact opposite of `highlight` and should be installed whenever `highlight` is installed.**

---

The bulk of your problem is that you're trying to use `success` in place of the `unhighlight` callback function.  The second line of your `success` function definitely belongs inside of `unhighlight`.

```
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
},
success: function(element) {  
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.fillimg').addClass('valid');       
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html(error.text());
}
```

Another potential problem you're created is that the plugin will not know how to remove the error message, because you've manually extracted the text from the error object and placed it inside your own element.  Using `success`, you'll have to then manually remove or hide this element if you want the error message to go away.

```
success: function(element) {  
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.fillimg').addClass('valid');
    $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html('');
    // or maybe this
    // $(element).closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').hide(); 
    // but you'll need a ".show()" at the end of your line in "errorPlacement"    
},
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to answer this.You are the best:)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Is better than the documentation (that doesn't tell when each function is called).