# how to use jquery validation plugin to submit a form using ajax and redirect to another page after success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

i'am trying to ajax submit a form to controller function and then redirect it to the page containing list on success, since i'am using jQuery validation plugin, i had to ajax submit like this

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/student/addstud",
        data: $('#sturegister').serialize(),
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.replace('/admin/student/add');
        }
    });
```

The details are added to the db, however, the form is not redirecting to /admin/student/add.is there any other way to do this ? thanks.

Comment: There's pretty much no point in using `.ajax()` if you _want_ to redirect.  Simply use the `<form>` `action` to point to your server-side script and handle the redirect from there.  Then you won't need the `submitHandler` callback as the default behavior of jQuery Validate is to just `submit` the form (`action`) when it's valid.

Comment: Thanks,could you also help me out with my question in this link [myanotherquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699709/combining-custom-error-placement-with-success-is-not-working-jquery-validate-plu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pretty much no point in using `ajax` if you want to redirect to a new page... that's like taking the bus when you really want to walk.  If you want to walk, just walk.

Simply use the  `action` to point to the URL of your server-side script...

```
<form action="/admin/student/addstud" ...
```

... and then handle the page redirect from server-side.  (That's how this used to be done before we started using `ajax`.)

Then you can totally remove the `submitHandler` callback function from `.validate()`, as the default behavior of jQuery Validate is to just submit the form (`action`) after the form passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

The `location.assign()` method loads a new document.

```
window.location.assign("http://www.your-full-url-here.com");
```

or

```
window.location.href ="http://www.your-full-url-here.com";
```

**One notice**: the `success` method of jQuery AJAX call is a function to be called if the **request succeeds**, but this does not mean, that the user data is *inserted correctly* into database, it means **only** that user browser have sent data to your server. What happens next - it is up to you.

Comment: I checked with assign() and href too. however, the form is not redirecting it remains on the same page after executing the code written within the addstudent function successfully,problem here is it is working fine with normal ajax call  and not within jquery validate submit handler