# jQuery Validate add and remove classes using callbacks

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am working with the jQuery Validate plugin and I am trying to use the `errorPlacement` and `success` callbacks to add and remove the bootstrap class `has-error`.

Currently, the `errorPlacement` callback works but since the `success` callback returns the error label (which I'm not using) I'm not sure what to do. I need access to my input again in `success` but I don't know how to do it.

```
$('#msform').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('valid form submitted');
        return false; // for demo
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
        $(element).css('border-color', '#a94442');
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label.removeClass('has-error').text('ok');
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    }
});
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I think I should be using highlight and unhighlight via [combining custom error placement with success is not working jquery validate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699709/combining-custom-error-placement-with-success-is-not-working-jquery-validate-plu).

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer pretty soon after I asked. I was using the wrong callbacks. For this type of desire you need to use `highlight` and `unhighlight`. But for some reason you also need to define `errorPlacement` if you don't want the added label.

```
$('#msform').validate({
    errorPlacement: function() {},
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
        $(element).css('border-color', '#a94442');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(element).css('border-color', '');
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('valid form submitted');
        return false; // for demo
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    }
});
```